# How to Password Protected for Assets folder through the Install Shield Script

Tags: installation, installshield, installshield-2015

I cannot able to protected the Assets folder through the Install shield Script.

Through Install Shield script I need to Password Protected Assets folder.
When Installing the application that time that time its should protected the folder.